# How to parse JSON data to Android?

Tags: android, json

I have followed a tutorial online and tweaked some of the code, I would like the application to read information from a different location. Currently the app is correctly reading the data from [here](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/). Now I would like to read data from [here](http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=NG27ND&format=json&num_of_days=2&key=1e79c0b14f180212131703). I'm looking to attain Observation Time, Temp_C & Visibility, I imagine I would need to change my code within the try { bracket in order to read this data? Any suggestions?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

// url to make request
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_DATA = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_OBSERV = "name";
private static final String TAG_TEMP = "email";
private static final String TAG_VISIB = "gender";

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParse jParser = new JSONParse();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

        // looping through All Contacts
        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String name = c.getString(TAG_OBSERV);
            String email = c.getString(TAG_TEMP);
            String gender = c.getString(TAG_VISIB);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(TAG_OBSERV, name);
            map.put(TAG_TEMP, email);
            map.put(TAG_VISIB, gender);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            contactList.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_OBSERV, TAG_TEMP, TAG_VISIB }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_OBSERV, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TEMP, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_VISIB, description);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum. In general you can read *sub objects* (things like `"name":{...}`) with `outer.getJSONObject("name")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to parse JSON data to Android?

So at first you should move your code where you are attempt to perfrom network connection(fetching data from JSON) to background Thread. Actually you're doing it at Main(UI) Thread and it's not very good and correct. If your app will be installed on a device that runs on Android 3.0+ you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and it's not nice, ins't?

Second, save your JSON and make some formatting to see its structure better. Multiset bracket { indicates JSONObject and bracket [ indicated JSONArray.

Now you should be able to parse JSON. Now i write you a little snippet of code how to start:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(sourceString);
if (o != null) {
   JSONObject data = o.getJSONObject("data"); // getting JSONObject with key data
   if (data != null) {
      JSONArray current = data.getJSONArray("current_condition");
   }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you should parse and get your values from that json :

```
JSONObject mMainObject = new JSONObject(myResponseString);
if(mMainObject != null){
    JSONObject data = mMainObject.getJSONObject("data");
    if(data != null){
        JSONArray currentCondition = data.getJSONArray("current_condition");
        if(currentCondition != null){
            for(int i = 0; i < currentCondition.lenght(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = currentCondition.get(i);
                if(obj != null){
                    String observation_time = obj.getString("observation_time");
                    String temp_C = obj.getString("temp_C");
                    String visibility = obj.getString("visibility");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Doing that you should consider the proper way to download the data from internet using `AsyncTask` for example. In this way it will not block your UI and your app will be more responsive.

Hope this help! : )

Comment: Wouldn't we have to use a FOR loop in case there are multiple array we have to retrieve from the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and prettiest way would be to create a DTO with the wanted properties and then use a library such as **Jackson** or **Gson** to map the JSON to object(s). Then it would be 2 lines of code instead of that 'manual parsing'.